# Add Zend form elements between radio buttons

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I would like to create a form with a text element between 2 options of the same radio button, so I can show it, using javascript, when the option is chosen.

Can anyone give some clues on how to do this?

Tanks

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381166/how-does-one-add-a-plain-text-node-to-a-zend-form answer your question?

Comment: No because I want to add the element between two options of the same radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [composite form element elements](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.form.decorators.composite.html). The bottom line is, natively you cannot do what you are asking. You have to create a new form element that renders the form element you want when each radio button is rendered.

Comment: Thanks Richard, but I was expecting an easier solution.